# hibernate: foreign key is primary key

Tags: hibernate

i have 2 tables relation one-to-one:

```
**message**(id, name, content)

**scheduled_message**(message_id, start_time, stop_time)
```

i use **message_id** as primary key of **scheduled_message** table.

my domain class:

```
public class Message {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String content;
    ...
}

public class ScheduledMessage {
 private Message message;
 private Date startTime;
 private Date stopTime;
}
```

i try write hibernate xml config to map 2 classes, but still error in message_id :(

```
<class name="Message" table="message">
  <id name="id" column="id">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="name" column="name" />
  <property name="content" column="content" />
 </class>

<class name="ScheduledMessage" table="scheduled_message">
  <id name="message" column="message_id">
   <generator class="foreign">
    <param name="property">message</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
  <property name="startTime" column="start_time" />
  <property name="stopTime" column="stop_time" />
  <one-to-one name="message" constrained="true"/>
 </class>
```

error: Could not determine type for: cbs.domain.Message, at table: scheduled_message, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(message_id)]

help me plz

thanks

Quan

Answer (score 4):

What you have here can be looked at in a different way. Rather than having `ScheduledMessage` expose a `Message` property, you could look at it that `ScheduledMessage` is a specialised type of `Message` - in other words a subclass. Hibernate allows you to map inheritance relationships like this in a number of ways - what you have here is called "table per subclass". If you read the [section of the Hibernate documentation on this sort of mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass), it should make everything clear and give you enough example code to get you up and running.

Alternatively, to stick with your current approach, you could map the id of `ScheduledMessage` as a [composite id](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) but with just a single component.

Comment: i only read relation basic mapping section, i will read inheritance section. thanks

Comment: for simple, i added id field in scheduled_message table (ugly), and it work well :|, thank you